# How to display product short description on "product review page"

Tags: magento

I had added product detail description by adding block in review.xml but I'm not getting which block to copy from where or what code to write to display short description on product review page?

Comment: Correct ans is in http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/69557/#t229001

Comment: Just try...
`<?php $_product = Mage::registry('product') ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $_product->getShortDescription ?>" />`

Answer (score 6):

In Magento EE 1.12 product pages (view.phtml) the method above

`<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductInfo()->getShortDescription()); ?>` borked...

but copying a method (already in view.phtml) and replacing the call with getShortDescription below worked

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'name') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductInfo()->getShortDescription()); ?>
```